# Python issue comparing decimated then upsampled 2D arrays

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, scipy, zooming

I am trying to study the deterioration of image quality as I progressively decimate a photo.

To do that I devised this experiment:
- take the input image and within a loop decimate by a factor of n and a factor of n-2 at each iteration, obtaining new images A and B
- upsample to original size A and B using sp.ndimage.interpolation.zoom, with zoom factors of n and n-2
- calculate the mse of the element by element difference between upsampled A and B at each iteration
- examine the change in mse from iteration to iteration.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io, feature, color, exposure

# import an image
tut=io.imread('http://www.two-views.com/images/Tut%20bone%20frag.jpg') 
tut=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('Tut.jpg'))  

# contrast stretching
p2, p98 = np.percentile(tut, (2, 98))
st_tut = exposure.rescale_intensity(tut, in_range=(p2, p98))

# decimate progressively, upsample, calculate mse
mse_tut = []

for n in range(6,50,2):
        temp1 = st_tut[::n,::n]
        temp2 = st_tut[::n-2,::n-2]
        tempz1 = sp.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(temp1, n, order=2)
        tempz2 = sp.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(temp2, n-2, order=2)
        mse_temp = ((tempz2 - tempz1) ** 2).mean(axis=None)
        mse_tut.append(mse_temp)
```

The problem is that I get this error message:

> ---> 11         mse_temp = ((tempz2 - tempz1) ** 2).mean(axis=None)
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (400,400) (402,402)

I am not sure why this is occurring since when I try this below, everything runs smoothly:

```
temp1 = st_tut[::10,::10]
temp2 = st_tut[::8,::8]

tempz1 = sp.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(temp1, 10, order=2)
tempz2 = sp.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(temp2, 8, order=2)

print temp1.shape, temp2.shape
print tempz1.shape, tempz2.shape

mse_temp = ((tempz2 - tempz1) ** 2).mean(axis=None)
print mse_temp
```

> (40, 40) (50, 50)
>
> (400, 400) (400, 400)
>
> 0.00981401032334

Comment: What is `st_tut.shape` and what iteration of `n` does it crash on?

Comment: st_tut.shape is 400,400, I am not sure at which iteration it crashes as I'm working in a notebook

Comment: I will bet money it's the first. Answer coming up.

Comment: Yep. It's the first. There's an easy fix without having to jump through hoops if you are OK with inexact-multiple upsampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the "smooth" case to get an understanding of what is going on. `temp1` is a `400x400 / 10 = 40x40` array. `400` divides by `10` exactly. Similarly `temp2` is exactly `50x50`. When you upsample, the arrays revert back to `400x400` since they are exact multiples of the dimensions.

Now let's take a look at what happens when you have `n = 6`. `temp1` is `400x400 / 6 + 1 = 67x67` array. Integer division applies here since you are actually stepping every sixth element. `temp2` is a `400x400 / 8 = 50x50` array. For `temp2`, `400` divides into `n-2` evenly. Now when you upsample, you get a `66x66 * 6 = 402x402` array and a `400x400` array.

You can test this out by doing the following:

```
 >>> import numpy as np
 >>> x = np.ones((400, 400))
 >>> x.shape
 (400, 400)
 >>> x[::6, ::6].shape
 (67, 67)
```

There are a couple of readily apparent solutions to this problem:

1. Select values of `n` for which both `n` and `n-2` such that `400` is a multiple of both. This is probably going to restrict the range of your operation significantly. While a legitimate solution, I do not recommend it.
2. `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom` takes a `float` as your zoom parameter. Instead of just passing in `n` and `n-2`, pass in `400 / temp1.shape[0]` and `400 / temp2.shape[0]`, respectively. For example, if `temp1` is `67x67`, this will scale it up by `5.97014925373` instead of by `6`, making the upsampled size exactly `400x400`.

Comment: I will have to think about wether I am fine with non integer upsampling, since I am trying to simulate a physical system with decimation of recording stations. But it is good to know it is an option, it may be perfect in many similar circumstances. As for your solution number 1, it would not be too bad if  I were to pad the input image to be of size 2^n, for example 512x512, as I mentioned in the comment to Oliver's answer. Thanks for a good answer anyway. I will have a hard time choosing between the two answers.

Comment: Let me say something to convince you: you are using a parabolic spline interpolation. The fractional distortion from the "true" un-decimated image created by adding a couple of rows and columns to a `400x400` image is miniscule. I suspect that it will not prevent you from modeling a physical system accurately.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is because the slicing operation, followed by the zooming operation, doesn't always return in an array that has the same number of elements.

The slicing operation, when used with a `step` of 2 (just an example), will only return an array that is twice as small if the original array had 2*n elements. Otherwise, it will return half the number of elements (rounded down) plus 1:

```
>>> [0,1,2,3][::2]  # 4-element array, will be reduced to 2
[0, 2]  
>>> [0,1,2,3,4][::2] # 5-element array, will be reduced to 3
[0, 2, 4]
```

"Zooming" those resulting arrays by a factor of 2, will only in the first case get you an array with the same number of elements, not in the 2nd case though.

So, the result depends entirely on the size of the input array: in your case, if it is a multiple of both n and (n-2), then you'll be fine. Otherwise, you're not.

I can summarize it with another example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> D = np.arange(10)
>>> for n in range(3,7,2):
...     print(D[::n].shape[0]*n, D[::n-2].shape[0]*(n-2))
... 
12 10
10 12
>>>
```

Compare that to the situation where `D = np.arange(15)` for example, which is a multiple of both 3 and 1, as well as 5 and 3 (the 2 subsequent iterations used in this example).

Comment: so, as long as I compare two sets that have been decimated by n1 and n2 that are both factors/dividers of the input array size,  I would be fine. For example I could pad the original image so as to be of size 512x512, and then use n and n/2:  4, 8,16, 32, 64, 128 and  2, 4,16, 32, 64. Sounds right?